# What software utility can set detailed Time Machine settings?

Tags: time-machine

I used to have a utility that allowed me some control over setting the frequency of Time Machine backups, but unfortunately I have lost the name of that utility. Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: [TimeMachineEditor](http://timesoftware.free.fr/timemachineeditor/)